# add dyanmically title attributes to select option elements javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to added to dynamically title attributes  to exiting selection option below code

```
selectbox.options[selectbox.options.length] = new Option(key, value);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: going to have to create  the option element with createElement instead....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new option does not support it (most browsers do not support title on options), but you would need to either select the option and add the attribute or use createElement to make the new element.

```js
const selectbox = document.querySelector('select')
selectbox.options[selectbox.options.length] = new Option('1', '1')
selectbox.options[selectbox.options.length-1].title = 'blah 1'

var opt = document.createElement('option')
opt.value = '2'
opt.text = '2'
opt.title = 'blah 2';
selectbox.appendChild(opt);
```

```html
<select>
</select>
```